# How to split array into multiple arrays with balanced sets of values

Tags: php, arrays

For example if my array has the values (10,10,3,4,7) and I need to split into 2 equal or near equal parts.  For example the result would be 2 arrays like:

Array #1 = array(10,7)

Array #2 = array(10,3,4)

Or if I need to split into 3 equal or near equal parts. For example the result would be 3 arrays like:

Array #1 = array(10)

Array #2 = array(10)

Array #3 = array(7,3,4)

I'm trying to figure out if there is a relatively easy way to do this with native array functionality.  Or is it best to just chunk the array and then iterate through the chucks and manually distribute the values.

Comment: There is no native PHP array functionality to provide this feature.

Comment: "Equal or near equal parts" ... how? As in array length, or sum of the array values?

Comment: The sum. Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `array_chunk` function for this purpose. However, it works with a fixed chuck size, rather than an amount of resulting chucks.

However, you can simply find out the desired size by using something like:

```
$output = array_chunk($input, count($input) / $parts);
```